# Help me install this wireless adapter

Tags: drivers, wireless, 18.04, usb, adapter

I'm having trouble figuring out how to install this wireless adapter dongle. The model is Alfa Network AWUS036ACM 802.11ac AC1200 High Speed USB Adapter.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. The default drivers are recognising my wireless adapter dongle.

Here is the wiki dev page for it: https://wikidevi.com/wiki/ALFA_Network_AWUS036ACM

And here is the actual page for this device: https://www.alfa.com.tw/service_1_detail/14.htm

I have experience with Windows and I have experience installing Ubuntu,Zorin OS and installing a brother printer proprietry driver in Ubuntu.

In the terminal when I type 'lusb' I get the following:

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0e8d:7612 MediaTek Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 413c:3010 Dell Computer Corp. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1a2c:0e24 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

In the terminal when I type: 'sudo lshw -C network' I get the following results:

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: c1
       serial: 00:25:22:a1:0f:c0
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.1-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.200 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:29 memory:fe3c0000-fe3fffff ioport:e000(size=128)
```

When I type 'sudo lspci -nn' I get the following:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [8086:0100] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0102] (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:1c14] (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation H61 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1c5c] (rev 05)
00:1f.2 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family Desktop SATA Controller (IDE mode, ports 0-3) [8086:1c00] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 05)
00:1f.5 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family Desktop SATA Controller (IDE mode, ports 4-5) [8086:1c08] (rev 05)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet [1969:2062] (rev c1)
```

When I type the following: 'lspci -nn | grep 0280' I get nothing but another command line.

When I type in terminal: 'nm-tool' I get the following message:

```
Command 'nm-tool' not found, did you mean:

command 'dm-tool' from deb lightdm

Try: sudo apt install
```

When I type 'sudo lshw' I get the following:

```
description: Desktop Computer
    product: To Be Filled By O.E.M. (To Be Filled By O.E.M.)
    vendor: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop family=To Be Filled By O.E.M. sku=To Be Filled By O.E.M. uuid=00020003-0004-0005-0006-000700080009
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: H61M-S
       vendor: ASRock
       physical id: 0
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: P1.00
          date: 02/25/2011
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 4032KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 4
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 128KiB
          capabilities: internal varies
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:1
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: 5
          size: 512KiB
          capacity: 512KiB
          capabilities: internal varies unified
          configuration: level=2
     *-cache:2
          description: L3 cache
          physical id: 6
          size: 3MiB
          capacity: 3MiB
          capabilities: internal varies unified
          configuration: level=3
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: c
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 4GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1067 MHz (0.9 ns)
             product: 99U5471-020.A00LF
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 0
             serial: D5262D26
             slot: A1_DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1067MHz (0.9ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMMProject-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-02 13:04+0000Last-Translator: Joel Addison <jaddi27@gmail.com>Language-Team: English (Australia) <en_AU@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2018-07-12 13:19+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18719) Synchronous [empty]
             product: Array1_PartNumber1
             vendor: A1_Manufacturer1
             physical id: 1
             serial: A1_SerNum1
             slot: A1_DIMM1
             width: 64 bits
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G640 @ 2.80GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 16
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G640 @ 2.80GHz
          slot: CPUSocket
          size: 2327MHz
          capacity: 3800MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave lahf_lm epb pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts flush_l1d cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=2
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 09
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=snb_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:26 memory:fe400000-fe7fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:27 memory:fe2f8000-fe2f800f
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:fe2f9000-fe2f93ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.18.0-18-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 4.18
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 0.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:28 memory:fe2fc000-fe2fffff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: b5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:24
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             version: b5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:25 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:fe300000-fe3fffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: enp2s0
                version: c1
                serial: 00:25:22:a1:0f:c0
                size: 100Mbit/s
                capacity: 100Mbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.1-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.200 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
                resources: irq:29 memory:fe3c0000-fe3fffff ioport:e000(size=128)
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:fe2fa000-fe2fa3ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.18.0-18-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 4.18
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@2:1
                   version: 0.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb:0
                      description: Keyboard
                      product: USB Keyboard
                      vendor: SEM
                      physical id: 3
                      bus info: usb@2:1.3
                      version: 1.10
                      capabilities: usb-1.10
                      configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=98mA speed=2Mbit/s
                 *-usb:1
                      description: Mouse
                      product: Optical Wheel Mouse
                      vendor: Dell Computer Corp.
                      physical id: 4
                      bus info: usb@2:1.4
                      version: 2.20
                      capabilities: usb-2.00
                      configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=2Mbit/s
                 *-usb:2 UNCLAIMED
                      description: Generic USB device
                      product: Wireless
                      vendor: MediaTek Inc.
                      physical id: 5
                      bus info: usb@2:1.5
                      version: 1.00
                      serial: 000000000
                      capabilities: usb-2.10
                      configuration: maxpower=100mA speed=480Mbit/s
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: H61 Express Chipset LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-ide:0
             description: IDE interface
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family Desktop SATA Controller (IDE mode, ports 0-3)
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ide pm isa_compatibility_mode_controller__supports_both_channels_switched_to_pci_native_mode__supports_bus_mastering bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ata_piix latency=0
             resources: irq:19 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:f0d0(size=16) ioport:f0c0(size=16)
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:fe2fb000-fe2fb0ff ioport:f040(size=32)
        *-ide:1
             description: IDE interface
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family Desktop SATA Controller (IDE mode, ports 4-5)
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.5
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ide pm pci_native_mode-only_controller__supports_bus_mastering bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ata_piix latency=0
             resources: irq:19 ioport:f0b0(size=8) ioport:f0a0(size=4) ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f070(size=16) ioport:f060(size=16)
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 1
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: DVDRAM GH24NS90
             vendor: HL-DT-ST
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/dvdrw
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             logical name: /media/eugene/ALFA
             version: IN01
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 mount.fstype=udf mount.options=ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8 state=mounted status=ready
           *-medium
                physical id: 0
                logical name: /dev/cdrom
                logical name: /media/eugene/ALFA
                configuration: mount.fstype=udf mount.options=ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8 state=mounted
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: ST500DM002-1BD14
             vendor: Seagate
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: KC45
             serial: Z3T5G9WL
             size: 465GiB (500GB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=a0ed5fb6-4c40-49bd-ae51-80e88a0f7db0 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
           *-volume:0 UNCLAIMED
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: mkfs.fat
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,1
                version: FAT32
                serial: 6336-e4fd
                size: 510MiB
                capacity: 511MiB
                capabilities: boot fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat name=EFI System Partition
           *-volume:1
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: 31bf5317-088f-4668-9689-e4c5b583abdc
                size: 465GiB
                capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2019-05-09 11:50:17 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2019-05-09 21:04:59 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro mounted=2019-05-09 21:05:03 state=mounted
```

This device is not listed in the ndiswrapper wiki.

When I type in the terminal: 'sudo iwconfig', I get the following:

```
enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

When I type in terminal: 'rfkill list', I get no results but just another identical command line.

Comment: How far did you get in following the documentation?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide  specifically 3.1 or identifying device.  The first step is `sudo lshw -C network` or list-network devices of class network, which provides details of what is connected, the chipset used - which is the 'key' to getting it to work. Please add this and any additional information to your question.

Comment: [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1141679/edit) the question to include results for `lsusb`

Comment: @Jeremy31 I have included lsusb in the question.

Comment: @guiverc I have editted my question as I have gone through the wireless trouble shooting guide but no help.

Answer (score 1):

In terminal do

```
sudo apt install build-essential git dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/mt7612u.git
sudo dkms add ./mt7612u
sudo dkms install mt7612u/1.0
cd mt7612u
sudo make installfw
```

Check `mokutil --sb-state` as Secure Boot needs to be disabled, reboot

Comment: 'make' all KVER=5.13.0-28-generic..........................(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for mt7612u: 1.0 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.13.0-28-generic (x86_64

Comment: @Fakhamatia ask a new question as the fix I used in that is likely in the kernel after 3 years and you have a different issue

Comment: I'm really scared of you and I do not ask questions.
Everyone gives negative points.
Everyone says duplicate questions.

Comment: @Fakhamatia try ubuntuforums.org then, no negative points or duplicate questions.  The MT7612 works fine in 5.13.0-28 kernel as I use one